Cost Effective Approach for Backing Up Delta Tables
I have a nearly 200 delta tables to be backed up into a seperate storage account of cool tier in Azure Storage.. This needs to be automated to run once every month.
I have considered the below options

Using Deep Clone Feature to clone the tables into the backup location. But this involves spinning up a databricks cluster which will incur significant additional costs due to huge size of the tables.

Using Copy Activity in Azure Data factory and Copy the files (Using a Binary Dataset) into the backup storage container. But I have to overwrite entire container every time. If I have copied incrementally some of the parquet files inside the backed up folders might not be deleted (which are deleted at source) and it may cause data issues while reading the backup files. (Please correct me if I am wrong here)


Out of these which would be the cost effective option?
Please let me know if there are any alternate ways...

The cost-effective option for backing up Delta tables to a separate storage account of cool tier in Azure Storage would be to use the Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory. However, instead of overwriting the entire container every time, you can load only the new or updated files from the source by using a time-partitioned folder or file name or by identifying new or updated files by their LastModifiedDate value. This will ensure that the backed-up files are always up-to-date and do not contain any outdated data.
